# how to read json one object data from restful service

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to read data from services using restful service. when I have one json object I am getting the issue. here is my code:

service code:

```
var ROAList =[];
var promise = $http.post(urlBase + '/' + 'getROAList', params)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        ROAList = data.item;
                        return ROAList;
                    })
                    .error(function (data) {                        
                        ROAList = 'error';
                        return ROAList;
                    });
            return promise;
```

In Controller:

```
var list =[];
$scope.ROAListItem = function(){
    list =service.getROAList();
}
```

In html:

```
<div ng-repeat="roa in list()" ng-click ="selectROAitem(roa.soa.name)">
  <div> {{roa.id}} </div>
 <div> {{roa.soa.name}}</div>
```

here is my json data:

```
{"item": [
      {
      "id":"001",
      "type":"001x2z"
      "sao":       {
         "itemNo": "3",
         "name": "001"
      },
   },
      {
      "id":"002",
      "type":"002x2g"
      "sao":       {
         "itemNo": "5",
         "name": "006"
      }
]}
```

it working fine for more than one item but I am getting an error for one item. for this json data:

```
{"item":{
      "id":"001",
      "type":"001x2z"
      "sao":       {
         "itemNo": "3",
         "name": "001"
      }
}
```

for this data ,I am getting 'cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

Comment: It needs to be an array for your ng-repeat to work.

Comment: `ng-repeat="roa in list"` maybe ? why do you call list() ; ? If you are using a function it's a bad practice, angular will do so much calls. And ng-repeat works for objects too.

Comment: sorry I misspelled. in ng-repeat I am using ROAListItem.

Answer (score 0):

Removed long winded answer. I didn't see your last section. Your multiple returns are all stored in an array, while your single return is not. So the dot access is incorrect for the single object.

In response to comment: again, you should really format the return data so that it's always in array, but otherwise you could do something like:

```
$scope.ROAListItem = function(){
    list = service.getROAList();
    if(!Array.isArray(list)){
      list = [list];
    }
}
```

Comment: how to access single object values?

Comment: You should be returning your single result still in an array. Otherwise, you'll have to do testing in the javascript. Like checking wither it's an array and then if not pushing it into one I guess. I'll put something in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to modify your service call like so:

```
$http.post(urlBase + '/' + 'getROAList', params)
    .success(function (data) {
        ROAList = data.item;
        if (!angular.isArray(ROAList)) {
            ROAList = [ ROAList ];
        }
        return ROAList;
    })
```

However, your service really should provide consistent behavior, returning an array even if there is only one item.

Comment: it worked for me. Thank you so much for the solution.

Comment: Great! If it was helpful, please accept and/or upvote the answer, thanks. :-)